# Google spreadsheet, i cant get the second archive feature on a different a different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

this is what I have done so far, it works on the first sheet called In house orders but i cannot seem to get the Archive feature to work on the second sheet called Outsourced orders. Am i missing something important out with the second archive feature?

```
function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

    var columnToSortBy = 10;
    var tableRange = "A:N3"; // What to sort. 

    if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
       var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
        range.sort([{
                 column: 10,
                 ascending: true
             }, {
                 column: 11,
                 ascending: true
             }, {
                 column: 12,
                 ascending: true
             }]);

            onEdit2(event);    
    }
  } // End definition of onEdit


function onEdit2(passedEvent) {     
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = passedEvent.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "In House Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue()    == "5. Archive") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}    

function onEdit3(passedEvent) {     
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();
    var r = passedEvent.source.getActiveRange();

    if(s.getName() == "Outsourced Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 &&     r.getValue() == "5. Archive") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
        var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
        s.deleteRow(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not calling onEdit3() function anywhere. Also there is no need of onEdit2() and onEdit3() functions. You can simply add the code like this:

function onEdit(event){
    var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

```
var columnToSortBy = 10;
var tableRange = "A:N3"; // What to sort. 

if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
   var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort([{
             column: 10,
             ascending: true
         }, {
             column: 11,
             ascending: true
         }, {
             column: 12,
             ascending: true
         }]);

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = passedEvent.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = passedEvent.source.getActiveRange();     
  if(s.getName() == "In House Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 && r.getValue()    == "5. Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
else if(s.getName() == "Outsourced Orders" && r.getColumn() == 10 &&     r.getValue() == "5. Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
}
  //onEdit2(event);    

  }
  } // End definition of onEdit
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The sort works but the archive doesn't. :( is there and easier way of doing this or have i just picked an awkward way of doing it?